# Upgrade xserver-xorg-input-synaptics

Tags: 11.04, xorg, 11.10, synaptics

I have a Thinkpad x220i. I'm using Natty. The touchpad works ok, but the pointer is "shaky" which is really distracting.

I tested the Oneiric Alpha 3 and there the Touchpad works fine out of the box. The synaptics package in the Oneiric Repos is 1.4.1, in natty it is 1.3.99.

How can i upgrade to the 1.4.1 version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there are any dependencies involved, but you can try to download 1.4.1 from [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics/1.4.1-1ubuntu1) (check the `Builds` at the bottom of the page for your architecture) and install it with `apt-get`

Comment: if he is on 11.04 how is he going to  install a package for 11.10 using 11.04 repos?

Comment: The link above provides the .deb binary directly. No repos are used. That's why i said that he might face depencency issues.